# Calculating distance between GPS data using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, distance

I have tables in SQL Server management studio containing the location of individuals by date/time along several months. The tables have the following fields: `AnimalID, Date/Time, Lat, Long, Global ID`. I am trying to calculate and return the distance between each pair of points in order of its movement without manually entering in the lat and long each time.There are many posts here about calculating distance between two points but I'm trying to run a query that will calculate the distance between each pair in consecutive order. Some of my tables have hundreds of locations.

My values might look like:

```
        `MD001 10/9/2019 1:00:00PM 40.73995 -111.8739
         MD001 10/9/2019 6:00:00PM 40.75068 -111.8782
         MD001 10/9/2019 10:00:00PM 40.74900 -111.89100`
```

I want to know the distance between 1:00PM and 6:00PM and then from 6:00PM and 10:00PM, and so forth. I want to accomplish this in SQL Server so that I can query out outliers in the data. Your insight is much appreciated. I also do not want to create a new field in this table.

Comment: I suggest you add a column to your table "distance from last point" or "distance to next point. Then you need to probably cursor through and calc the values one by one. It may be useful to use `LAG` for this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The first step is to write a select query that represents the start and end points on one row. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm to calculate the distance between points is called [Harvesine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula.)

To calculate the distance between 2 points in SQL Server you have 2 options:

```
POINT 1 = 151.209030,-33.877814
POINT 2 = 144.971431, -37.808694
```

**Option 1**. You can do your own implementation of the harvesine formula:

```
select
    2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(POWER((sin(radians((-37.808694 - -33.877814) / 2))),2) + cos(radians(-33.877814)) * cos(radians(-37.808694)) * POWER((sin(radians((144.971431 - 151.209030) / 2))),2)))
```

Note this will give you the distance in kilometer. This is defined by the multiplier **6371**. To get the distance in miles replace 6371 by **3959**

If you do a search on the [harvesine formula + sql](https://www.google.com/search?q=harvesine%20formula%20sql&rlz=1C1GCEA_enAU872AU872&oq=harvesine%20formula%20sql&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j0l5.4319j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can find more in depth details about this implementation.

**Option 2.**. Use SQL Server built-in functions.
In order to do that you'll need to convert your lat and long columns to geography datatype and then use the STDistance function to calculate the actual distance.

The statement below should give you an idea to get started:

```
select
    cast('POINT(151.209030 -33.877814)' as geography).STDistance(cast('POINT(144.971431 -37.808694)' as geography)) as distance_in_meters,
    cast('POINT(151.209030 -33.877814)' as geography).STDistance(cast('POINT(144.971431 -37.808694)' as geography)) / 1000 as distance_in_km
```

The default result will be in meters.

Note there's a slight difference between these 2 options when they are applied to the same coordinates. So if you need precision then you might want to do some further investigation on why that is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was very helpful. I guess I'm struggling with applying Option 1 formula to the entire table. I don't want to have to manually enter in the lat and long for every point as there are hundreds of rows I need to find the distance for.

Comment: My answer is just demonstrating how you can implement the formula. You obviously need to replace the hardcoded points by the lat and long columns from your table and build your own select statement.

Comment: Do you have any helpful links on what the select statement might look like? This is the part I am struggling with and can't figure out how to tell it to compute the distance between consecutive pairs. Thanks.

Comment: Are your values from above all in one column in the table? That is, do you have a row with a column whose value is `MD001 10/9/2019 1:00:00PM 40.73995 -111.8739`? If so, the lack of normalization is going to be rough.

Comment: No those values are all in separate columns: AnimalID, Date/Time, Lat, Long

Comment: @James. What do you exactly mean by "consecutive pairs"? Both options will take 2 points (2 x latitude and longitude coordinates) as an input. Generally speaking, you will need 4 columns PointA_Latitude, PointA_Longitude, PointB_Latitude, PointB_Longitude to be able to calculate the distance between such points.

Comment: I'm trying find the distance between pairs in order of sequence. Ex: AB-BC-CD-DE-EF for over a 100 points. I don't want to enter each pair of lat long points into this formula. I think using the Lag function might work, I just don't know how to implement it into the haversine formula.